# How to split `npm install` to two steps to perform offline builds?

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, npm-install, software-packaging

I am trying to build an application requiring NPM on [Open Build Service](https://build.opensuse.org/). When building the application locally, one of the steps is
`cd`ing into a directory containing `package.lock` and then running `npm install`.

For obvious reasons this fails on a computer with no internet access.

What I would like is to download the required node modules somehow and then add them as part of the application source.

If `node_modules` included only text files, I could just tar it up and unpack it on the remote server. Unfortunately, some of the modules include binaries which are built by NPM using `g++`, and I don't want to include opaque binaries as a “source”.

How can I split `npm install` into two steps:

1. to be performed locally and producing human-readable source
2. to be performed by OBS using downloaded sources and not requiring internet access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is `npm install --ignore-scripts`, the second is `npm rebuild`.